# Printing name of second lowest mark scorer in a nested list and arranging in alphabetical order in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

```py
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = []
        for _ in range(int(input())):
            name = input()
            arr.append(name)
            score = float(input())
            arr.append(score)

        array = [arr[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(arr), 2)]
        marks = []
        for j in range(0, len(array)):
            marks.append(array[j][1])
        marks = list(map(float, marks))
        marks.sort()
        seclow = marks[1]
        for k in range(0, len(array)):
            if (seclow == float(array[k][1])):
                print(array[k][0])
```

```
**SAMPLE INPUT:**

    5
    Harry
    37.21
    Berry
    37.21
    Tina
    37.2
    Akriti
    41
    Harsh
    39
```

```
**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

    BERRY
    HARRY

**MY OUTPUT:**

    HARRY
    BERRY
```

The only problem is ordering the names with the lowest scores in alphabetical order. I should use lists to pass the test case. So, what changes should be done to the code?

Comment: You're appending the name and then the score to the same list for every entry. If you reorder it at all, the names and scores will get mixed up. Considering this is a prime case for key value pair. I would make a dictionary with scores as the keys and list for the names/values. That way you can call sort on them.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for helping me out. Learnt a lot from you. @Pygirl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using any imports and in less code, it can be done this way.
I also put it into a function just to make it a little cleaner and so you can reuse it elsewhere if needed.

```
def main():
    scores_dict = {}
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name, score = input(), float(input())

        if score not in scores_dict:
            scores_dict[score] = []
        scores_dict[score].append(name)

    # Delete the min score key and names so that we can grab the second min
    del scores_dict[min(scores_dict.keys())]

    # Get new min score.
    min_score = min(scores_dict.keys())

    # Sort new min score.
    scores_dict[min_score].sort()
    # Print each name in results
    [print(i) for i in scores_dict[min_score]]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This made it a lot easier for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check via here: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/fMD7OgxYC7

Instead of defining list. Store it in a dictionary. This will give you space-optimized solution. Then sort dictionary by value. add the names having the score in a dictionary.

**Try:**

```
import collections
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = {}
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        arr[name] = score

    dd = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for k,v in arr.items():
        dd[v].append(k)

    x = sorted(dd.items())
    sec_low = sorted(x[1][1])
    for i in sec_low:
        print(i)
```

---

**Input:**

```
5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
```

**Output:**

```
Berry
Harry
```

---

**x:**

```
[(37.2, ['Tina']),
 (37.21, ['Harry', 'Berry']),
 (39.0, ['Harsh']),
 (41.0, ['Akriti'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Handles duplicate lowest and duplicate second lowest.

Sample input: {"hri":6.2,"dav":1.1,"asv":1.1,"wrs":12.3,"dup":6.2,"awe":43.2,"asw":22.2,"asd":6.2}

Output:  ['asd', 'dup', 'hri'] can be printed joining to "\n"

```
def lowest_scores(names_scores):
    
        lowest_score=min(names_scores.values())
        
        lowscorers=[]
    
        low_scorer_dict = { k : v for k,v in names_scores.items() if v != lowest_score}
        
        second_lowest_score = min(low_scorer_dict.values())
    
        for k,v in low_scorer_dict.items():
            if v == second_lowest_score:
                lowscorers.append(k)
            
        return sorted(lowscorers)
```